# Loading each line in a text file into a different vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following file:

```
0 1 4 8 
2 3 0 1 2 3 
2 1 3 1 1 2
```

The file will always have three lines and i want each of the line to be in a separate  vector

i have a code like this but as one can see it doesn't store the text in distinct vector.

```
  fid = fopen('my_file.txt');
  while ~feof(fid)
     line=fgetl(fid);
     C = str2num(line)
  end
```

Edit: I got the answer by using cellarrays. If  someone can do it better, please answer below.

```
fid = fopen('my_file.txt');
CCSMat = {};
count = 1;
while ~feof(fid)
    line=fgetl(fid);
    C = str2num(line);
    CCSMat(count) = {C};
    count = count+1;
end

v1 = cell2mat(CCSMat(1));
v2 =  cell2mat(CCSMat(2));
v2 =  cell2mat(CCSMat(3));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [textscan](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function can be helpful in this case, while keeping on reading the file line by line:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');

res = cell(3,1);
res_off = 1;

while (~feof(fid))
    line = fgets(fid);
    vector = textscan(line,'%f','CollectOutput',true,'Delimiter',' ');

    res{res_off} = [vector{:}];
    res_off = res_off + 1;
end

fclose(fid);

v1 = res{1};
v2 = res{2};
v3 = res{3};
```

Despite being a little bit slower, you can also use [strsplit](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) together with [str2double](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) within the same approach:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');

res = cell(3,1);
res_off = 1;

while (~feof(fid))
    line = fgets(fid);

    res{res_off} = str2double(strsplit(strtrim(line),' '));
    res_off = res_off + 1;
end

fclose(fid);

v1 = res{1};
v2 = res{2};
v3 = res{3};
```